# Connecting to PingFederate server for SSO using JavaScript/Angular

Tags: single-sign-on, ws-federation, pingfederate

I found corresponding nuget package in visual studio, but my client is not c#. As i am new to SSO concept i am having trouble to get things started. Any help in this regard would be good.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

We (disclaimer: I work for Ping) have a great "how to" article that should give you all the considerations and option for how to SSO enable your application regardless of the language and framework you've built it with.

Please have a read here: https://www.pingidentity.com/content/developer/en/resources/application-integration-overview.html